# Pyinstaller have exe accept user input

Tags: python, python-2.7, exe, pyinstaller

I have a working Python script that has some variables that need user input. When I compile using pyinstaller the exe does not ask for any input.

How can I accept input?

Comment: Have you tried running your program from the windows command prompt (cmd)?

Comment: You can also build a gui (e.g. with tkinter)

Comment: Look into the `argparse` module...